# Trusting External organization ADFS server and consuming openid Connect token

Tags: single-sign-on, ws-federation, adfs3.0, adfs4.0

ADFS server 2016 supports openId connect. I have external organization that hosts ADFS server , I want my web application to get authenticated  from External ADFS server using openIdConnect .

Question : As per  Microsoft docs . If we want to consume external organization's ADFS we should host ADFS in our organization also. My application should trust ADFS hosted inside my organization ,instead of trusting external ADFS directly.

Here I want to know why we cannot directly trust External ADFS  using opendiconnect ? It seems possible. what is reason of not trusting external ADFS directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both models work. If your application plans to have users from multiple organizations, it is better to have your app trust an internal org ADFS which can then be federated to multiple of these organizations with simple configuration changes. This makes the application simpler where it is dealing with only one IDP. An additional advantage for having an internal ADFS is that any authentication policy changes can be managed fully at internal ADFS layer and not potentially requiring application changes.

However, if your application is only going to support one external organization, you can do this directly in the application. Both models work for this.

Hope that helps.

Thanks //Sam (Twitter: @MrADFS)

Comment: @samuID . Is it possible to trust an external adfs using SAML protocol directly